# My system requires ntp package while for Rhel 8 I can only download chrony

Tags: redhat, ntp, rhel8, chrony

Is there a way to use ntp as the  manual install of ntp rpm is failing.

Manually installing ntp is giving me thefollowingn errors on Rhel 8.

```
/usr/bin/chkconfig is needed by ntp-4.2.8p17-150000.4.25.1.x86_64
        fillup is needed by ntp-4.2.8p17-150000.4.25.1.x86_64
        libdns_sd.so.1()(64bit) is needed by ntp-4.2.8p17-150000.4.25.1.x86_64
        pwdutils is needed by ntp-4.2.8p17-150000.4.25.1.x86_64
        timezone is needed by ntp-4.2.8p17-150000.4.25.1.x86_64
```

The packages mentioned in the output are also not being installed

I tried installing the npm package manually by using its rpm

Comment: "_My (annot.: RHEL 8) system requires `ntp` package_", may we ask why? What is the reason or which software brought in this dependency?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom software and migration to chrony requires a lot of code rewrite

Comment: Strange use case for me, anyway, "_The packages mentioned in the output are also not being installed_", right, that's the expected behavior. If you like to install a package like `ntp` which depends itself on other packages like `chkconfig, fillup, pwdutils, timezone` you will need to resolve such dependencies before too, means you have to install them also, but upfront. Sometimes that will lead to more dependencies.

Comment: This this is almost only about RPM, package management and dependencies in RHEL-like based distribution, you might find an answer under unix.stackexchange.com, serverfault.com or superuser.com. In this case is no programming involved, just administration and operation ...

Comment: And maybe in case it might help, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/infrastructure-services_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8#implementation-of-ntp_time-synchronization and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/configuring-time-synchronization_configuring-basic-system-settings#assembly_achieving-some-settings-previously-supported-by-ntp-in-chrony_configuring-time-synchronization